# Local notification in android app with cordova / phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I made a local notification like that :

```
/* local notification */
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    window.plugin.notification.local.add({
        id: 1,
        message: "test",
        title: "Hello !",
        icon: 'file://img/logo/true.png',
        sound: 'TYPE_NOTIFICATION'
    });
}, false);
```

But there is a problem : the sound it's the only event played...

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications I miss something ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have the sound, but not the message